# Splitting declaration and assignment with string array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment, assign, variable-declaration

There is probably a really simple solution to this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I can find countless examples of how to create a string array in C++, but I can't find one that shows how to make the assignment separate.

I currently have a declaration with assignment that looks something like this:

```
static const char *desc[3] = { "apple", "banana", "orange" };
```

What I would like to do is split the declaration and assignment to separate statements. The declaration:

```
static const char *desc[3];
```

...but I can't seem to figure out how to do the assignment. I have tried the following:

```
desc = { "apple", "banana", "orange" }; // Expression must have a modifiable lvalue. error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
*desc = { "apple", "banana", "orange" }; // Too many initializer values. error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const char*' in assignment
desc[3] = { "apple", "banana", "orange" }; // Too many initializer values. error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const char*' in assignment
*desc[3] = { "apple", "banana", "orange" }; // Expression must have a modifiable lvalue. error: assignment of read-only location '* desc[3]'
```

Comment: Do you have to use a const char? if so it could only be initialized at creation.

Comment: There would be nothing wrong with `const char *desc[3] = { "apple", "banana", "orange" };`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, there is. I want to have an `if` statement which assigns `desc` with different values.

Comment: You are not prevented from doing that. `const char *desc[3]` declares an array of 3 pointers to `const char*`. If you initialize with `const char *desc[3] = { "apple", "banana", "orange" };` there is nothing that then prevents you from making a later assignment to one of the pointers, `if (somecondition) desc[2] = "grapes";` (now you cannot modify the *string-literals* pointed to by each of the pointers, but you can change what the pointers point to)

Comment: I wish to change all of them or none of them, so it doesn't make sense to make initial values if they'll all be changed, and it would be annoying to have statements for changing each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example allocates the array on the stack, which is only possible because the compiler knows the size (since all strings are fixed length and provided during declaration).

When you separate declaration and initialization, your compiler has no way of knowing how much memory to allocate on the stack, so you need to change your type into a pointer (which has a fixed size, no matter what it points to):

```
static const char** desc;
```

and then use `new` to allocate enough memory for the array:

```
desc = new const char*[3]{ "apple", "banana", "orange" };
```

However that means that you now also must `delete[]` the array pointed to by `desc`, as otherwise you get a memory leak.

Much better would be to use modern container types like `std::vector` and `std::string`:

```
static std::vector<std::string> desc;
```

and then

```
desc.push_back("apple");
desc.push_back("banana");
desc.push_back("orange");
```

These classes take care of all the nasty memory management for you under the hood.

---

Another alternative, if you really want a raw array, and don't want to rely on `new[]` and `delete[]`is to declare a fixed size array with enough space for your strings like so:

```
static const char desc[3][128];
```

and then later copy the string values into that block of memory:

```
std::strcpy(desc[0], "apple");
std::strcpy(desc[1], "banana");
std::strcpy(desc[2], "orange");
```

However I really don't recommend doing this, as you risk bugs in the long run when you add or remove strings, or change their lengths etc.

Comment: In my specific case, the possible values that I assign are always going to be the exact same size in memory. Is there a way to optimize the code if I know this?

Comment: @AaronFranke Optimizations always depend on a multitude of factors, so there is no real catch all. Sometimes the question also is: Do you really need a particular optimization? My general approach is to first implement readable and understandable code, and then profile it for performance and resource usage and optimize specific parts of the code that have been identified as critical. I really reccommend you just use `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::array<std::string, 3>`. That being said, the last solution in Emil Vatai's answer might be the "optimization" you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> I currently have a declaration with assignment that looks something like this:
>
> ```
> static const char *desc[3] = { "apple", "banana", "orange" };
> ```

This is not "assignment". This is initialisation.

> I can't seem to figure out how to do the assignment.

Arrays are not assignable. You cannot assign to an array.

If you want to modify elements of an array after it has been initialised, you either need to iterate each element and assign them one by one:

```
const char *arr[] = {"apple", "banana", "orange"};
static_assert(std::size(arr) == std::size(desc));
std::copy_n(arr, std::size(arr), desc);
```

Or you can wrap the array into a class, in which case an assignment operator will be generated for you. There is a standard template for such array wrapper `std::array`:

```
static std::array<const char*, 3> desc;
// later
desc = {"apple", "banana", "orange"};
```

Comment: Typo: `initialisation.`??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not a typo.

Comment: Err..... okay, different side of the pond I guess `:)` (west side - `"initialization"`)

Comment: "Arrays are not assignable.You cannot assign to an array." Why?

Comment: @AaronFranke because the rules of the language say so.

Answer (score 1):

Max Vollmer give some excellent suggestions, although using `new` and raw pointers is discouraged in "modern C++" (post C++11). See [1] (Sutter is a member of the C++ standard committee, so he knows his thing.

So if you are going for "true C++ way" to have an array of strings, than you should go for:

```
std::vector<std::string> dest_a;
dest_a.push_back("apple");
dest_a.push_back("banana");
// or
std::vector<std::string> dest_b(3);
dest_b[0] = "orange";
dest_b[1] = "pear";
dest_b[2] = "plumb";
```

If you **need** the raw pointers, I think I'd go for the old C `strcpy` functions.

---

Although, you might just be looking for this.

```
  static const char *ptr[2];
  ptr[0] = "orange";
  ptr[1] = "pear";
```

---

[1] https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/

Answer (score 0):

your declaration is wrong because when you write char [3] it will make your character array containing 3 characters, not an array with 3 different unlimited characters.

Comment: I don't see a `char [3]` in the question.